# Is it possible to use Spring 3 @Autowired annotation inside @Service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using class that is not called by my `@Controller` directly and when I try to use `@Autowired` propeprty in that class what is defined as `@Service`, property is `null`. But `@Autowired` with same markup will work inside `@Controller`.

Example code:

```
@Service
public class UsernameValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired private UserDao userDao;

    // code here when used, userDao is always null

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work perfectly fine, if you have the following in your `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.yourproject" />
```